# Rails 3 No route matches {:action=>"show", error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

While there are similar questions on this error, most relate to how Rails route handle pluralisation, whereas this is different.

I have a link on the 'show' view page within a controller called MemberPage which I need to link to the 'new' action within a controller called Post

```
<%= link_to ((content_tag :i, "", :class => "icon-pencil") + content_tag(:span, 'create')), new_members_community_post_path %>
```

Within routes I have

```
resources :post
```

which produces the following related line in rake routes

```
new_members_community_post GET        /members/community/post/new(.:format)                                  members/community/post#new
```

Hovering over the link shows

```
127.0.0.1:3000/members/community/post/new
```

Clicking on it produces the error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"members/community/member_page"}
```

Rails is matching both the wrong controller and the wrong action from that shown in rake routes

I've tried creating explicit match rules in routes.rb, eg (within the members/community namespace)

```
match '/new-post' => 'post#new'
```

and also replacing the link_to path with

```
:controller => :post, :action => :new
```

but cannot find anything that works

Comment: Did you try restarting the server?

Comment: Is there a previous route that may match the request? Routes have precedence from top to bottom in your routes.rb file.

Comment: Restarted each time I modified routes.rb, no other matching routes. I also have resources :member_page beside resources :post - have changed order but no diff. Have tried same link within a post/show view but no diff

Comment: update: seems that if the word 'new' appears anywhere in the route - eg match 'post/make_new', write_new etc, then it throws the error